# Forecast automation when dealing with many time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

When working with a time series, it's worth plotting it and analyzing its features, such as trend, seasonality, etc. These features suggests some models for you to try out. In the end, you choose the model that has the highest accuracy in a test set of never seen observations.

But if you have to forecast several hundreds of time series, you don't have the time to analyze each one separately. In this case, I wonder if the best choice is to automate the fitting of several of the most commonly used models, and choose the best performing one for each time series in the end.

This brute force automation approach is used in practice? If so, is there any implementation of this automation (e.g. a programming package/library)? What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Or there is another way companies use to forecast a lot of time series?

Comment: There are specific tools designed to estimate hundreds of time series at a time. I never paid lots of attention because I do not do this. You might look at the M contests in the literature as a starting point (although that is fairly dated now). I am pretty sure SAS does this in one of its packages you might look at the documentation. I do not know if R does, I have never seen a package that does this. I don't know the details of how this works, I am sure it is an automated process using something like AIC or MAPE to make choices.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/on-the-automation-of-time-series-forecasting-models-technical-and-organizational-considerations-286db3120c8e